# Compare time in gorm: time.Time or string

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

We are using [gorm v1.9.11](http://github.com/jinzhu/gorm)and mysql.

```
// before is string like "2019-01-15T06:31:14Z"
if len(before) > 0 {
    // TODO: Determine time format
    beforeDate, e := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, before)
    if e != nil {
        ...
    }
    // TODO: Pass in string?
    statement = statement.Where("created_at < ?", beforeDate)
}
```

I have two questions:

1, any problems in the above piece of codes? I found it took about 5 minutes to finish the query given `before`. If no `before`, it tooks 14 seconds.

2, it is OK to pass string like "2019-01-15T06:31:14Z" as argument in `statement.Where("created_at < ?", beforeString)`?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

We have an index on `created_at`, the query plan shows that it will filter 8millions rows based on `created_At`. I guess this is the reason.

Now, trying to avoid this index to be used.

Comment: Your code looks fine. How long it takes to execute the query depends on the number of records you have and whether you have index for the query.

Comment: @icza can I pass string as argument instead of time.Time in the where statement to compare time?

Comment: I'm not sure but how long would it take for you to try it? I'd rather stick with `time.Time` so you'll get no timezone surprises.

Comment: @icza I tried using string as argument. it seems working. I checked gorm doc, not sure whether string is suggested or not.

Comment: @BAE : what driver do you use to connect to your MySQL database ? I think yoru question about "string or time.Time ?" is more about the driver, and MySQL itself (which, IIRC, should convert your string anyway)

Comment: is the statement with the string faster ? (note : I would be surprised if it were, it would probably indicate that `created_at` is actually not stored as a date in MySQL)